# Get the data in the app before we build it in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-3

I am new to phonegap I was trying to install a plugin in my project.So after I ran the command in CLI ie

`phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin.git` then I ran

`phonegap install android`

and then all my previous files got replaced with the default phonegap file.

So, is there any way I could get back the previous files or else I am in a complete mess.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build with the PhoneGap CLI, files in platform/android/assets/www are replaced with files from www/. Unfortunately your overwritten files are lost unless you had them checked into version control.